# Convert C bitwise logic to Logic into PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to convert the following C for loop into PL/SQL

```
for ( int i = 0; i <=3, i++ ) 
       _Size[ i ] = (byte) ( ( intSize >> ( i * 8 ) ) & 0x000000FF );
```

So that it runs with an Oracle database.

Comment: Do you know what the function is doing? If you explain the functionality it might be possible to do this with out a transliteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions for [Bitwise Operations in PL/SQL](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2006/06/01/174.aspx)

Also there is a summary in this [Oracle FAQ](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/bitwise.html)